# Could not open connection hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate to connect to MSSQL 2012, I have `cfg.xml` like this

```
 <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://USER-PC:1433;databaseName=AvtoParki;integratedSecurity=false               databaseName=AvtoParki;integratedSecurity=false</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>-->
<property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
<!-- Mapping files -->
<mapping class="Employee" />
```

my PC `userName` is `"user"`, and I'm connecting to SQL by windows authentication I don't have any password on it , so When I run application `session.beginTransaction()` throws error: `"Login failed for user 'user'. Couldn't open connection"`. Can anyone solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Integrated security should be set to True as you want to connect using Windows Authentication:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">
jdbc:sqlserver://USER-PC:1433;databaseName=AvtoParki;integratedSecurity=true;
</property>
```